# Hibernate: generated properties for many-to-one relationships?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to configure a hibernate object to handle foreign keys which have default values at the database level.  I have a User object with an emailFormat column which is a key into an emailformat type table.  The User table's emailFormat has a default set at the database level, and also a not-null constraint.

My hibernate file is:

```
<class
    name="User"
    table="USER"
>
...
  <many-to-one
       name="emailFormat"
       class="EmailFormat"
       not-null="true"
  >
  <column name="EMAILFORMATID" />
</many-to-one>
```

I would like to create a new User object without setting emailFormat and have Hibernate recognize that it is a generated value.  Instead, Hibernate attempts to insert a 'null' for that value and the insert fails.

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("EMAILFORMATID")

The docs for generated properties seem to indicate that what I want is impossible, because: 1.) it looks like only a property can be generated, not a key for a many-to-one relationship; and 2.) the docs say:

"Properties marked as generated must additionally be non-insertable and non-updateable."

Which won't work for me, because while the db generates default values, I need to be able to change (override) them sometimes.

Sometimes I have experienced the docs being wrong, or the bleeding edge having some undocumented or poorly documented way to do things.  I have searched on-line without finding anything, but I'm hoping someone else knows better.

Any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having default values at the database level set the defaultvalue in the constructor of the domain object(User in your example) for the field `emailFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Hudon: That would work if the hibernated object were the only thing that ever inserted these objects into the DB, but unfortunately that's not the case.  Got to deal with some legacy stuff, and, I think, stuck with defaults.  Would like to make Hibernate play nicely with them.

I can re-define all the defaults in code and require anyone instantiating a new domain object to set those defaults (or do it in the constructor, etc.), but that will mean duplicating the logic of what defaults are what - all that now resides in the DB.  Plus, it's extra work.  Hoping Hibernate can just play nicely.  It's possible there's no way to do it.